# Eclipse upgrade from 3.8.2 to 4.5.2

Tags: java, eclipse

I have upgraded my eclipse project to **4.5.2** from **3.8.2**.
I was able to build the project but while running I am getting many errors for missing bundles:

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:  com.codegear.sanctuary.client.headless [11]
>   Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime

Now this is a plugin/jar from eclipse. I don't have rights to modify them.
So in this case how to fix such errors?
Any help is appreciated.

Detailed  log:

Here is the log:
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The System Bundle was updated. The framework must be restarted to finalize the configuration change
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.install(ConfigApplier.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.Activator.start(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    ... 25 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The System Bundle was updated. The framework must be restarted to finalize the configuration change
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.install(ConfigApplier.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.Activator.start(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)

!ENTRY MigrationBenchmark 4 0 2016-04-14 01:01:09.840
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: MigrationBenchmark [2]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui

```
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

!ENTRY WindowTesterPlugin 4 0 2016-04-14 01:01:09.845
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: WindowTesterPlugin [3]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui

```
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us more detailed messages from the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory,

Comment: Make sure you've adjusted the Target Platform to reflect the new versions in 4.5.2.

Comment: Java 7 JRE/JDK is required to run Eclipse v4.5, please verify the version.

Comment: actually I have to upgrade my project from java 7 to 8. For that I had to upgrade  eclipse as older versions dont support java 8.